# DDR3-1600 CL11 + DDR3-1333 CL9 on a 1333MHz motherboard for dual channel?

Tags: memory, motherboard

The question is to match DDR3-1600 CL11 and  DDR3-1333 CL9 for dual channel 1333MHz motherboard.

Will DDR3-1600 CL11 on a 1333MHz motherboard become DDR3-1333 CL9?

Here's my calculation:

Assume the delay time is fixed.

Delay time = delay-cycles * cycle time = delay-cycles / freq.

And we know 11/1600M ~= 9/1333M

Am I right? Or, is my assumption valid?

And the final question: is this a good configuration for dual channel?

Comment: It will not, but it doesn't have to match, they will just be running at the same (lower) frequency.

Comment: The lower frequency is 1333, since 1600>1333, right?  I just want to know how many wait states would it be.  Will that be CL11 or CL9?

Comment: Only the higher frequency would downclock, but its CL speed would remain the same, since thats indepdant of the frequency.

Comment: So, which means 1600-CL11 will run at little bit slower than 1333-CL9, @ 1333MHz system, right?